# Reporting errors and bugs in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

How to report Errors or bugs found in SQL Server to Microsoft SQL Server Team ?

Comment: What is the intent of that piece of code? `select CAST(123 as varbinary)` returns `0x0000007B` what is the desired result of the concatenation with `a`?

Comment: it is not my main request, it is just example, my main request is how to Report Microsoft SQL Team about any found bugs or errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct.

You have two operands.

The literal `'a'` is treated as `varchar(1)` and the second one is `varbinary(30)` (30 is the default if no length is specified in a `CAST`). It is invalid to concatenate these **mixed** datatypes.

- `[var]char` + `[var]char` works fine
- `[var]binary` + `[var]binary` is also fine

To answer your question though bug reports should go [on the Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) but always worth sanity checking that it is a genuine bug first!

Comment: This error is not exactly what I mainly need, it was just an example notice, and you are right about.
Yes the Connect Site is what I seek, thanks Martin